# Unity doesn't start

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

I downloaded Ubuntu 11.04 onto a USB stick in order to run a live version from there. For some reason, Unity doesn't start, but Gnome does. Also, I tried changing the session environment(e.g., Ubuntu/classic), but they all load Gnome.

So, why doesn't Unity work?

Answer (score 1):

It could be your computer hardware. Unity is kind of graphics hardware dependent IIRC. There is Unity 2D option w/c is almost the same if you just want to try it out.  It (Unity) will work on a VirtualBox upgraded to 4.0.6 with the latest guest additions.

And once you've downloaded Unity 2D, if you decide to go that course, logout and makes ure you select Unity 2D from the options at the login screen. :)

Answer (score 1):

Something similar happened to me.

I logged in Ubuntu classic mode and when I went back to Unity it didn't loaded i just got the wallpaper, and no panel or launcher.

I did this to fix it:

Logged in Ubuntu classic mode (without effects), then opened CCSM, deactivated gnome compatibility and activated unity plugin.

In my case was some conflict between these two plugins.

If your hardware does not support 3d acceleration try installing unity 2d or using a proprietary driver for your graphics card.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem even after installing the latest drivers and fiddling with CCSM. I found an entry for Metacity in "Startup Applications" that was clobbering Unity on login. Disabling that entry fixed the problem for me.

If that doesn't work, you can try adding an entry for /usr/bin/unity.